# Flask pass string to jinja?

Tags: xml, flask, jinja2

Is it possible to pass an f string? I think would this be using jinja? Sorry still learning...

I am also experimenting with XML format.. But if I run this

```
from flask import Flask, Response


class MyResponse(Response):
    default_mimetype = 'application/xml'

class MyFlask(Flask):
    response_class = MyResponse

    
app = MyFlask(__name__)

num = 55
name = Jon Smith

string = f'{name} Employee ID {num}'

@app.route('/')
def get_data():
    return '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name> {string} </name>
</person>
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In Postman this shows up as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name> {string} </name>
</person>
```

Comment: use this {{string}}

Comment: It shows up as `<name> {{string}} </name>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.format` to pass the string

```
app = Flask(__name__)

num = 55
name = 'Jon Smith'

string = f'{name} Employee ID {num}'
print(string)
@app.route('/')
def get_data():
    return '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
    <name> {string} </name>
</person>
'''.format(string=string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: Any chance you could help me out with this one :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513948/attributeerror-flask-object-has-no-attribute-count-obj