# `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'count_obj'

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

So I have a function below `count(n)` that just creates some random numbers and I am attempting to experiment if I can pass the `count_obj` random number value to a Flask App that runs on a separate thread. Newbie experiment here sorry if it seems a bit strange.

```
from random import randint

def count(n):
    print(','.join(str(abs(x)) for x in range(n, -n, -1)))

count_obj = count(randint(0, 10))
```

My entire Flask App code is here that has the `count(n):` function embedded. The counting thread runs every 5 seconds with the `POOL_TIME` setting.

```
#https://www.edureka.co/community/30828/how-do-you-add-a-background-thread-to-flask-in-python

import threading
import atexit
from flask import Flask, Response
from random import randint


POOL_TIME = 5 #Seconds
commonDataStruct = {}# variables that are accessible from anywhere
dataLock = threading.Lock()# lock to control access to variable
yourThread = threading.Thread()# thread handler


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    def interrupt():
        global yourThread
        yourThread.cancel()

    def doStuff():
        global commonDataStruct
        global yourThread
        with dataLock:
        # Do your stuff with commonDataStruct Here
            def count(n):
                print(','.join(str(abs(x)) for x in range(n, -n, -1)))

            count_obj = count(randint(0, 10))

        yourThread = threading.Timer(POOL_TIME, doStuff, ())
        yourThread.start()

    def doStuffStart():
        global yourThread
        yourThread = threading.Timer(POOL_TIME, doStuff, ())
        yourThread.start()

    # Initiate
    doStuffStart()
    # When you kill Flask (SIGTERM), clear the trigger for the next thread
    atexit.register(interrupt)
    return app

app = create_app()



class MyResponse(Response):
    default_mimetype = 'application/xml'

class MyFlask(Flask):
    response_class = MyResponse


#num = app.count_obj
num = 5.5
string = f'CounterObjTest {num}'

@app.route('/')
def get_data():
    return '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <name> {string} </name>
</test>
'''.format(string=string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What's noticeable in the code above is `num = app.count_obj` commented out. If I use this I will get an error `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'count_obj'` but If i use `num = 5.5` the separate thread appears to work to count random numbers every 5 seconds and I can see the XML stuff through the browser.

How could I pass the `count_obj` to be viewable through the browser? I think I need to create another class but I am still learning threading! Thank you

Comment: Do you want to pass count_obj variable to flask jinja is that what you saying?

Comment: if i m not wrong is that what you saying?

Comment: Yes exactly pass the `count_obj` to Flask Jinja!