# How to write user input to HTML file?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, printing, output

My question is, how do I take two different user input in Python and write them to an HTML file, so that when I open the file, it will display the user's input?

I am not looking to open the HTML file in the browser from Python. I just want to know how to pass Python input to the HTML file and how exactly that output must be coded into HTML.

This is the code:

```
name = input("Enter your name here: ")
persona = input("Write a sentence or two describing yourself: ")

with open('mypage.html', "r") as file_object:
    data = file_object.read()
    print(data)
```

I want to take the name input and persona input and pass it to a HTML file, open the file manually, and see it display as a webpage. The output would look something like this when I open the file:

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>
... Enter user name here... # in which i don't know how to print python user 
# input into the file
</h1>
</center>
<hr />
... Enter user input here...
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask pass string to jinja?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506055/flask-pass-string-to-jinja)

Answer (score 1):

use `format` to add `user input` into html file

```
name = input("Enter your name here: ")
persona = input("Write a sentence or two describing yourself: ")
resut = """<html><head><body><center><h1>{UserName}</h1>
</center>
<hr />
{input}
<hr />
</body>
</html>""".format(UserName=name,input=persona)

print(resut)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key feature here is to put some dummy text in the HTML file, which to be substituted:

**mypage.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>
some_name
# input into the file
</h1>
</center>
<hr />
some_persona
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Then the Python code will know exactly what to do like that:

```
import os

name = input("Enter your name here: ")
persona = input("Write a sentence or two describing yourself: ")

with open('mypage.html', 'rt') as file:
    with open('temp_mypage.html', 'wt') as new:
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace('some_name', name)
            line = line.replace('some_persona', persona)
            new.write(line)

os.remove('mypage.html')
os.rename('temp_mypage.html', 'mypage.html')
```

Comment: is there any possible substitute for import os?? Such as import pathlib / from Path import pathlib??

Comment: Or basically, a way that does not require the import os module?

Comment: @carson, yeah I just checked and it seems to be possible. I just always have trusted the "os" module, that's all. Cheers!